# does silverlight 3 support GUID in xaml?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I have a question similar to this - [Does Silverlight xaml support Byte Data Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208717/does-silverlight-xaml-support-the-byte-data-type). Does silverlight xaml support Guid datatype. I m trying to set Guid in my xaml which is a declared as property in c# class library. is this possible? I tried using

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

and using

```
<sys:Guid>F16095D1-1954-4C33-A856-2BDA87DFD371</sys.Guid>
```

but that not working !

Please suggest if there is a work around for this.

Thanks in advance
Sai

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A work round would really depend on why you want to include a raw Guid in Xaml in the first place.

You can't use `sys:Guid` in the way you are attempting to because Xaml has no way to know how to convert the content of the element to an instance of a Guid structure.  In fact you can't include an empty `sys:Guid` although I don't know why you can't do that (not that it would ever be useful to do so anyway).

However if you are trying to assign a value to a property on an instance of a type you control then you can work round this with a type converter.  First add a `GuidConverter` to your project:-

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Globalization;

namespace SilverlightApplication1
{
    public class GuidConverter : TypeConverter
    {
        public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
        {
            return sourceType == typeof(string);
        }

        public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type destinationType)
        {
            return destinationType == typeof(string); 
        }

        public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
        {
            return new Guid((string)value);
        }

        public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
        {
            return ((Guid)value).ToString("", culture);
        }

    }
}
```

Now decorate your type's property with a `TypeConverter` attribute:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(GuidConverter))]
public Guid MyGuidValue {get; set; }
```

Now in your xaml you can do this:-

```
<local:MyType MyGuidValue="F16095D1-1954-4C33-A856-2BDA87DFD371" />
```

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler solution is to use the `sys:string` type instead.

I added the following XAML to a Resource dictionary, and had no problems extracting it in C# code:

XAML

```
<sys:String x:Key="MyGuid">F16095D1-1954-4C33-A856-2BDA87DFD371</sys:String>
```

C#:

```
string guidString = Application.Current.Resources["MyGuid"] as string;
Guid guid = new Guid(guidString);
```

Jim McCurdy

[YinYangMoney](http://YinYangMoney.com/)

Comment: Thank you! easy approach but kind of messy...but I will surely try this!