# Silverlight XAML: "The type 'Byte' was not found."

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, byte

I'm having trouble serializing a XAML resource dictionary file for my Silverlight application that uses a Byte as an entry. I've more or less copied the examples of how this has worked for others, but still seem to be missing something.

The XAML:

```
<ResourceDictionary
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
   xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

   <system:Byte x:Key="PrimaryLightColorAlphaValue">#FF</system:Byte>
...
```

The system namespace is included as per other examples, and Intellisense appears to validate the XAML pre-compilation/runtime, yet I still get an error at runtime when the file attempts to load:

> The type 'Byte' was not found. [Line: 6 Position: 24]

Any ideas? Hopefully I'm missing something simple.

Answer (score 2):

The only native types supported in Silverlight's flavor of XAML are `double`, `int`, `bool`, `string` and `Uri`. I know no smart way around this bogus limitation, sorry.

Reference: [XAML Usage Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd638655%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: You could always convert to `int`s

Comment: Damn. At least that answers my question.

Comment: Au contraire, apparently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208717/does-silverlight-xaml-support-the-byte-data-type

Comment: A `TypeConverter` attached to a property is OK, but I don't see how it'll work for bare `byte`s as in the OP.

Comment: Absolutely. They'll need to roll their own composite.

Comment: Yup :) either that or switch to `int`